# Hodge Laplacian and scalar

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I'm reading Nakahara GEOMETRY, TOPOLOGY AND PHYSICS now.Then, Hodge Laplacian is given by
\begin{align}
\Delta=(d+d^{\dagger})^2=dd^{\dagger}+d^{\dagger}d
\end{align}
For example, we consider 0-form $f$, then $d^{\dagger}f=0$
\begin{align}
\Delta f&=d^{\dagger}df=d^{\dagger}(\partial_{\mu}f dx^{\mu})\\
&=-\ast d \ast(\partial_{\mu}f dx^{\mu})=-\ast d(\frac{\sqrt{|g|}}{(m-1)!}\partial_{\mu}f g^{\mu \lambda}\epsilon_{\lambda \nu_2 \cdot \nu_m} dx^{\nu_2}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\nu_m})\\
&=-\ast \frac{1}{(m-1)!}\partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f] \epsilon_{\lambda \nu_2 \cdot \nu_m} dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\nu_2}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\nu_m}
\end{align}
So far, so good, but I don't understand the next transformation.
\begin{align}
\Delta f&=-\ast \partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f] g^{-1} dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^m\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f]
\end{align}
Why did $g^{-1}$ come up? I would appreciate it if you could tell me. For your information, $\ast$ is defined as follows.
\begin{align}
\ast (dx^{\mu_1}\wedge dx^{\mu_2}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\mu_r})=\frac{\sqrt{|g|}}{(m-r)!}\epsilon^{\mu_1\mu_2 \cdots \mu_r}\ _{\nu_{r+1}\cdots \nu_{m}}dx^{\nu_{r+1}}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\nu_{m}}
\end{align}
where $m$ is just dimension of manifold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this expression,

$-\ast \frac{1}{(m-1)!}\partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f] \epsilon_{\lambda \nu_2 \cdots\nu_m} dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\nu_2}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\nu_m}.$

Now,

\begin{equation}
\ast dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\nu_2}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\nu_m}=\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon^{\nu\nu_2\cdots\nu_m}.
\end{equation}

Therefore, the first expression becomes,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f] \epsilon_{\lambda \nu_2 \cdots\nu_m}\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon^{\nu\nu_2\cdots\nu_m}
\end{equation}

Using equation (7.171b) of the book, we can express the Levi Civita tensor with all contravariant indices in terms of the tensor with all covariant indices,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f] \epsilon_{\lambda \nu_2 \cdots\nu_m}\sqrt{|g|}g^{-1}\epsilon_{\nu\nu_2\cdots\nu_m}=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\partial_{\nu}[\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu \lambda} \partial_{\mu}f] \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}(m-1)!\delta_{\lambda}^{\nu}.
\end{equation}
The second expression follows from a property of the Levi Civita tensor (see Wikipedia). This gives the desired expression.